# Compressing a COUNTIFS formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to help a friend with a really simple `COUNITF/COUNTIFS` formula.  Data is like:

[image]

Objective is to count the data cells excluding *mike*, *john*, *judy*.  Current formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A13,"<>mike",A2:A13,"<>john",A2:A13,"<>judy")
```

which returns the correct value 3.  Problem is that he has much more than three names to exclude.  We would like to list them in column **B** and have the formula refer to the list (*otherwise the formula becomes huge*).  We have tried:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A2:A13,"<>B2:B4"))
```

both normal-entered and array-entered, but it yields 12 !

Strangely enough, if we want to **include** rather than **exclude** then :

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A2:A13,B2:B4))
```

works. I offered a VBA solution, but that was rejected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISERROR(MATCH($A$2:$A$13,B:B,0))))
```

[image]

or just subtract from the whole:

```
=COUNTA(A2:A13)-SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A13,B2:B4))
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU.......................it's an approach I never would have considered.